# How to fetch an entity with all children associations in one query?

Tags: java, sql, database, set, jpql

I have a JPA entity called `Ave` that has two child associations as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ave")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Ave implements Serializable {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Contact.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "ave_contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ave_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "potentialbuyer_id"))
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  private List<Contact> allPotentialBuyers = new ArrayList<>();


  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Bid.class, mappedBy = "ave")
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
  private Set<Bid> bids = new HashSet<>();
```

I want to load all `Ave` entities with ALL `bids` and with ALL `allPotentialBuyers`  in one JPQL Query (with possible multiple SQL selects). (How) is it possible?

Comment: It seems that this is not possible, see  https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-select-multiple-many-to-many-associations-efficiently-using-jpql-and-hibernate/1344/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join fetch`:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
"select a " +
"from Ave a " +
"left join fetch a.allPotentialBuyers " +
"left join fetch a.bids", Ave.class
).getResultSet();
```